# Display Computer Info on an ASP.NET Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to build a page for end users to visit (in our MPLS Network) and it show the following information in regards to them:

- Computer Name
- OS
- Disk Space
- Memory
- IP Address
- Active Directory User Name
- Password Expiration Time (As defined by Global Policy)

Maybe a few other things such as Trend Micro Office current version vs. their version, # of MS Updates needed (we utilize WSUS), and a few other things in the future.

My question is how would I pull this information from the user when they visit the page? What is the proper function for this? Anyone have examples they wish to share for me to learn by if possible?

Comment: On a side note, for those with high rep, how does one report a deleted comment of mine that I didn't delete? See below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011090/display-computer-info-on-an-asp-net-page/3011105#3011105

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to show all of this using C#. C# is a server side language and therefore, only has access to that information relative to the server it's being hosted on. You might be able to access this information from a java applet that runs on the page in the user's browser, but I'm not sure. There are usually security restrictions involved.

Comment: I was hoping to stay away from Java if at all possible.

Comment: Yes..sure don't need java when u r having asp.net with c#.
ASP.NET gives u the solution for this.

Comment: ok...so I need to write the web application in ASP.NET with C# and then it will give me the desired information?

Comment: You will still only get the information that the browser sends to the server - Computer name, OS, IP Address and AD user name.  The other stuff is not discoverable from the server side.

Comment: @John - based on your comments here and your other answer, do you even know what ASP.NET is?

Comment: `Comment Deleted?` Where did my comment go? I was interacting with user 'John'. When he refers to @jdk it was my comment. Should this be reported as an issue?

Comment: If OP is in the .NET world he may want to leverage his skillset by using Silverlight which is effectively .NET client-side, instead of learning Java client-side.  I believe Microsoft has other WPF-based technology that can be leveraged over the web to varying levels of security which could be trusted to provide certain levels of info about the client machine. Leaving this as a comment and will let someone more experienced with client-side .NET take over.

Comment: I will check out Silverlight if that will do what is needed. I am new to the .NET side, so, any step to complete this is a first for me. I really need to accomplish this, so, whatever route I need to go is fine with me.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow *your* web page to gather all this information about your users, what's to stop some *other* web page from doing the same?

Comment: What you can do on an **internal** network, challenging for NTLM creds for example, would be very different than just any 'ol webpage.  There's not a single source of info for this, but all of it's achievable.

Comment: Not my downvote, but it's not clear how your answer relates to the question. (*I* know what you're getting at, but still.)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this without writing a browser plug-in or a java applet.

The information is not available through javascript, and it's not in the headers sent by the browser. This is by design, for security reasons.

*Edit* This answer only applies to public pages; I see from subsequent comments that it will be intranet-only.

Comment: This is inside a closed network, presumably by IP you could get to some or all of this info, since you could be challenging for NTLM credentials as well.

Answer (score 0):

So it's in an intranet only? You could use the client computers IP address (as reported by the [Request.UserHostAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)) and then query your domain controller for the information (via the [DomainController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domaincontroller%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) class and the collections/methods it exposes).

Most of the information you're after will be available via the Domain Controller, and some of the others can be retrieved by using remote [performance counters](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/dotnet/perfcounter.aspx) (for example, you could query for free disk space using the LogicalDisk\% Free Space counter).

Comment: Yes. This will only be available to those are logged onto (in office or VPN) the network. So, not just anyone can access it.

Comment: could you give some sample code? Looking at your link for the DomainController class, I don't see how to get this information.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at XAML Browser Applications (XBAP). It's similar in a way to Silverlight except you get the advantages of the full .Net framework. To be able to access some local resources you would need to use the trust mode as explained below.

[WPF XAML Browser Applications Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/wpf-xaml-browser-applications-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

[Creating a Full Trust .xbap Application](https://web.archive.org/web/20150622075949/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/karstenj/archive/2005/11/29/498061.aspx)